# Query a single table with relationship database Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, jquery, json, flask, sqlalchemy

I've got three tables: User, Role, Department

I want to query all the user with selected following filters: 
`Department.name , Role.name and User.degree`

I can't find a solution to this problem, any suggestion would be great!

Here's my models simplified:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    degree = db.Column(db.String(20),default=None)
    department_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('departments.id'))
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))


class Department(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "departments"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(100), unique=True)
    user = db.relationship('User', backref='department',
                                lazy='dynamic')

class Role(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'roles'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(100), unique=True)
    users = db.relationship('User', backref='role',
                                lazy='dynamic')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
session.query(User).filter(
User.department.has(name='some_name)).filter(
User.role.has(name='some_role')).filter(
User.degree == 'some_degree')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple query with joins. You can modify "department" with your department filter and "role" with the same. You should modify the select part (`session.query(User.id)`) with the fields you want.

```
users = (session.query(User.id).join(Department, Department.user == User.id).join(Role, Role.user == User.id).filter(Department.name=="department").filter(Role.name=="role").group_by(User.id))
```